# bash array printf in gnu parallel

Tags: bash, gnu, printf, gnu-parallel

I am trying pass bash array variable, that contain two elements to GNU parallel script:

```
echo ${opts[@]}                                                                                                                                                    
-s 100206 -i /input/100206/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/100206_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz -s 100408 -i /input/100408/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/100408_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz
```

I tried to run it like this

```
printf '%s\n' "${opts[@]}" | parallel --jobs 8 --timeout 250% --progress recon-all {.} -all -qcache
```

It looks like I use `printf` wrong:

```
printf '%s\n' "${opts[@]}"                                                                                                                                         
-s                                                                                                                                                                                         
100206                                                                                                                                                                                     
-i                                                                                                                                                                                         
/input/100206/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/100206_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz                                                                                                                            
-s                                                                                                                                                                                         
100408                                                                                                                                                                                     
-i                                                                                                                                                                                         
/input/100408/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/100408_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't want to use the `\n` in `printf()`.

Comment: It looks like your array doesn't have two elements. What is the output of `echo ${#opts[@]}`?

Comment: `echo ${#opts[@]}                                                                                                                                            
    8`
but the number of elements could be bigger then 8

Comment: @Inian that's won't work, script recon-all should take arguments like this: 1st  bash array element:
`recon-all -s 100206 -i /input/100206/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/100206_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz -all -qcache`
2nd bash array element:
`recon-all -s 100408 -i /input/100408/unprocessed/3T/T1w_MPR1/100408_3T_T1w_MPR1.nii.gz -all -qcache`
with parallel

Answer (score 0):

I think you want 4 records per command:

```
printf '%s\n' "${opts[@]}" |
  parallel --jobs 8 -n4 --timeout 250% --progress recon-all {.} -all -qcache
```